# Speeding up notifications for autotest on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I've figured out how to run guard on my ubuntu desktop to use while doing Ruby on Rails development. The notifications are quite useful, but lag forever behind guard, so if I run a test, I'll wait for two minutes afterward waiting for the notifications to catch up to the end.

It's not absolutely necessary, but rather annoying and would be even more useful if they could only display the final test results (for example, "20 examples, 2 failures") instead of the results of each individual test.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Here is the solution:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications
They say there is no official way to configure notification but there is an unofficial patch allowing to configure it widely. There you can reduce it's appearance time.

Also worth noticing, I had an issue appearing the same guard notifications several times. I found that it's somehow due to backup files with ~. Solved it adding

```
ignore /~$/
```

to the top of the Guardfile. I found the information about it here:
https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/153